# In Django turtoring book chapter 3, there is {% if latest_question_list %} ,but I got none

Tags: django

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
```

In my index.html page, I added code as it says in the book. But `latest_question_list` is shown as none, I didn't get anything like the display. Can someone help me solve this issue?

**EDIT**

index.html

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
<ul>
{% for question in latest_question_list %}
<li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a> 
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

from .models import Question


def index(request):
  latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
  template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
  context = {
    'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    }
  return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
  question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Comment: Did you pass it through your view?

Comment: Yes I did pass it from view to template.

Comment: Did you create questions during part 2 of the tutorial? You can try adding it through the admin portal like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial02/#explore-the-free-admin-functionality)

Comment: everything looks fine with your code, check in your admin that there are actually some `Question`s

Comment: I have checked admin , there are some items in there and I make sure its not empty

Answer (score 1):

- checkout your template path, maybe you are sending data to the wrong template. as [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something) says:

  > First, create a directory called templates in your polls directory. Django will look for templates in there.
  >
  > Your project’s TEMPLATES setting describes how Django will load and render templates. The default settings file configures a DjangoTemplates backend whose APP_DIRS option is set to True. By convention DjangoTemplates looks for a “templates” subdirectory in each of the INSTALLED_APPS.
  >
  > Within the templates directory you have just created, create another directory called polls, and within that create a file called index.html. In other words, your template should be at polls/templates/polls/index.html. Because of how the app_directories template loader works as described above, you can refer to this template within Django simply as polls/index.html.
- also you can print the list in your `index` view, to make sure your `latest_question_list` is not empty.

**Edit**

- so as you find out, the `context` key name you use in your template must be same you created in view.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Now it works, my mistake was I thought in this statement {context:'latest_question_list',latest_question_list} the name doesnt matter so I made up with another. It turned out it didnt work. I wrote like this context:'aaa',latest_question_list